# Can we improve the grammar of the canned comments?

Tags: discussion, support

Perhaps I'm nitpicking too much, but if the site is going to write a comment for me I'd like the grammar to be correct.

For instance, if I select a possible duplicate for a question, the site, on my behalf, posts:

> possible duplicate of Another question?

I see two problems there.

1. The first letter of the sentence should be capitalized.
2. My comment takes on the ending punctuation of the question title. I'm not asking a question; I'm making a statement.

I'd like to see it, at minimum, say:

> Possible duplicate of "Another question?".

Finally, the language is a bit awkward, as the sentence skips the subject and goes straight to the predicate. I see the value of the brevity, but I don't think adding a short subject would be that terrible. This would leave us with something like:

> This question is a possible duplicate of "Another question?".

Is this too much to ask?

Comment: I think this would have to be done at SE-level rather than single-site level. Might be worth bringing this up on Meta SE.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Alright, if that is the case, migration or repost and delete?

Comment: migration. Though it may still be worth letting people here at it first, see what they say.

Comment: These comments come from the software itself, so I definitely doubt that they are per-site customizable at all. Note that you are free (during the five-minute grace period) to edit the comment however you like; just hover over it and click "edit" like with any other comment.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yeah, I've been editing them. It just seems to be setting a poor example in the first place. I now see this topic was brought up five years ago on meta.SE with no plans to fix. Oh well.

Comment: Remember where Stack Exchange comes from: programming, and related fields (this all started with [so]). Brevity *for the sake of avoiding the use of needless words* tends to be much more accepted not to say outright sought there. Not saying that makes it right or wrong *today*, but I often find it helps to consider the history of something when trying to figure out why it is the way it is. :-)